# Oddness - 'in spite of error and illusion' vs 'because of error and illusion'?

Tags: difference, sentence-meaning

> [65% down the page](http://www.newstatesman.com/culture/2014/10/richard-dawkins-doesn-t-deserve-fellow-atheist-s-smears): 5. Evolution (aka Dawkins) cannot explain why humans have true beliefs. Gray writes:
>
> As [Arthur Balfour] he framed the problem in The Foundations of Belief in 1895, “**We have not merely stumbled on truth in spite of error and illusion, which is odd, but because of error and illusion, which is even odder.**”

Would someone please explain why 'because of is odder than 'in spite of'? In the context of stumbling on truth, how does 'because of error and illusion'differ from 'in spite of error and illusion'?

Comment: We can paraphrase that quote to: amid error and illusion, we have found the truth, which is odd; but what is even odder is that we've found the truth exactly because of such error and illusion.

Comment: The distinction here is really just an Off Topic matter of philosophy/religion. I'm guessing Balfour believes there's such a thing as "divine truth" (which includes "knowing" that God exists, that good and evil are objectively-definable things, etc.). He takes it for granted that a "naturally evolved" brain could never acquire the ability to know about such things, so the fact that we *do* proves the knowledge must come from God. And you can *only* acquire such knowledge through humble acceptance of your own fallibility, and faith in God (so it's *because*, not *in spite of* fallibility).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about philosophy, not language as such. At the level of English *language*, the difference between *in spite of* and *because of* is General Reference.

Comment: The poster is asking for the meanings of certain phrases in context. We answer lots of questions of that sort. If the context had not been a highly controversial philosophical subject, would you be voting to close? For example, if he had asked about a text saying "our company sales are down because of the latest advertising campaign, not in spite of the advertising campaign".

Comment: @FumbleFingers To pursue the off-topic philosophical discussion: The writer's point is not that there is "divine truth" as opposed to "secular truth", but that if the human mind has evolved through natural selection, then we have no reason to believe that our minds are capable of discerning truth. They would have evolved to succeed in the struggle to survive through natural selection, not to determine abstract philosophical truth. Thus any thoughts you have that do not help you to survive are not reliable, but the result of random processes.

Comment: @LePressentiment: Would you clarify what you mean by "the rank of oddness"? Are you asking about the different degree of oddness?

Comment: @ColleenV: Better now?

Answer (score 5):

> “We have not merely stumbled on truth in spite of error and illusion, which is odd, but because of error and illusion, which is even odder.”

My main approach with dense writing is to break it into thoughts or ideas. Usually each word in the sentence was chosen carefully to convey a certain meaning or tone, so I find it helpful to expand a single sentence into multiple sentences. With writing like this, it is difficult to break out each word or phrase and tie it to one idea, so there is some overlap in the parts of the sentence I used to deduce the ideas.

**We found truth accidentally.** (*We ... stumbled on truth*)

**We found truth even though we were hindered by error and illusion, which is unexpected.** (*in spite of... which is odd*)

**Error and illusion are the reasons we found truth, not just obstacles to finding truth, which is even more unexpected.** (*but because of... which is odder*)

This isn't really an explicit idea in the sentence, but rather something implied by the tone:

**That we found truth in this way is astounding** (implied by *have not merely ... but because* astounding isn't the perfect word but it is close enough I think)

Answer (score 2):

This is a philosophical/religious/scientific argument that gets outside the scope of this forum, but to try to discuss just the language part of it:

The writer is saying that if the human mind is the result of random, chance processes, i.e. evolution, regulated only by natural selection, then there is no reason to believe that any thoughts that we have are objectively true. Natural selection would select for thoughts helpful to survival versus thought not helpful to survive, but "helpful to survival" and "true" are not necessarily the same. For example, "tigers kill people" is a thought that is both true and helpful to survival: If I believe this is true, I will stay away from tigers, and thus live longer. "Orange flowers kill people" is, to the best of my knowledge, not true, but believing that would not hurt my chances for survival. If I avoid orange flowers because I think they will kill me, so what?

So to the point: No one doubts that discerning the truth is sometimes difficult. There are optical illusions; we may make mistakes in observation, measurement, or logic; etc. Nevertheless, we might arrive at truth "in spite of error and illusion", that is, we might, through sufficient effort, distinguish illusions from accurate observations, and weed out logic errors from our thinking. The idea that we could arrive at truth "in spite of error and illusion" is not particularly surprising. But if the human mind has evolved by chance processes, then we have no basis to distinguish truth from error, because our minds, our thinking, are fundamentally unreliable. If we have arrived at truth, it is through a process based on chance and randomness. That is, we have arrived at truth "BECAUSE of error and illusion".

Thus the evolutionist is faced with the paradox that if his theory is true, then by definition his mind is incapable of objectively determining that it is true. All he can say is that belief in evolution must not harm the individual in the struggle to survive.

Answer (score 0):

(We assume that) we reached a goal, even though we didn't know where that goal was when we started.  In other words, we stumbled on it.  There existed obstacles.  We reached the goal in spite of the obstacles.  There were reasons that we could reach the goal.  We reached the goal because of those reasons.  Those reasons are exactly the same as those obstacles.

We reach that goal, not merely in spite of the obstacles, but because of the obstacles.  If it is odd that we can overcome the obstacles at all, it is even odder that the obstacles themselves are the reasons that we reach the goal.

That is the reason that "because of error and illusion" is odder than "in spite of error and illusion".  Saying that "in spite of error and illusion" is odd implies that those obstacles seemed to be insurmountable.  Saying that "because of error and opposition" is even odder implies that it seems self-contradictory for the solution to be the same as the problem it solves.

That something which should keep us from a goal is the very something that lets us reach that goal poses a philosophical problem to the author of your quote.